# How do I restore .bat files association with the system (make them run when double-clicked)?

Tags: windows, file-association

What do I set the 'Opens with...' property to in order to get the system to run .bat files again (when they are double-clicked)?

Somehow my boss convinced his workstation that the handler for `.bat` files was supposed to be Word. Now, when double-clicking `.bat` files, they're opened up in Word.

Comment: right click .bat file -> Open with... -> select MS Word, check "Always open with this program", click OK.  bam, your extension is now registered to Word.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How do you remove a default program association for file types in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/49615/how-do-you-remove-a-default-program-association-for-file-types-in-windows-7)*.

Comment: FYI, .bat files are not executables.  They are interpreted scripts.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I think you'll have to remove the .bat file association from the registry (using the regedit program).

According to this [forum thread on LockerGnome](http://help.lockergnome.com/windows/BAT-File-Association-Broken--ftopict514456.html), you need to remove registry settings **underneath** this key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat
```

You'll probably want to back up registry before doing this, just to be safe.

Comment: For you minimalists out there, I would add that I was successful by removing only the UserChoice subfolder. Once it was gone, the default Execute behavior was restored.
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat\UserChoice

Comment: I removed the entire ``.bat`` key and things came back to normal. For some reason (I suspect antivirus) I couldn't rename the ``UserChoice`` key.

Comment: The lockergnome link in the above post is broken, and when I try the Wayback Machine, the only results I get are web pages which are blank apart from the misspelt text "hello. This is the page you requestd."

Comment: The fastest way is to open a command prompt as admin and enter
`assoc .bat=batfile`.  This will fix it immediately without the need to restart.

Comment: @MarkFGuerra actually, this is not minimalist. The `HKCU` entry, which is a single user's setting for Explorer, takes precedence over the user defaults, located at `HKCU\Software\Classes\.bat` (describing `\.bat` to the whole user account instead of just Explorer), which in turn is an automatically generated copy from `HKCR\.bat` (the default for the OS), unless modified.

Answer (score 35):

This registry key file will do it. Copy and paste to a text file called "restore.reg", and double click it to merge into the registry.

It will clear out any per-user setting you may have accidentlly created for .bat files, and restore the system defaults, including the `.bat` <-> `batfile` file type relationship as well as the actual parameters for launching a `batfile`.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat]
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.bat]
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\batfile]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.bat]
@="batfile"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\batfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"
```

Comment: also had to run for cmd files on my machine

Comment: After doing this, while double clicking bat file, I am getting error like "a.bat is not a valid win32 application"

Comment: Works perfectly but to take affect I had to kill `explorer.exe` and run as a new task again using Task Manager.

Comment: A faster way is to open a command prompt as admin and enter
`assoc .bat=batfile`.  This will fix it immediately without the need to restart.

Answer (score 18):

None of the answers above fixed it for the machine I was working with, but what fixed it was starting an Admin Shell and running

```
assoc .bat=batfile
assoc .cmd=batfile
```

Comment: This is the solution for Win 2008 Server, cmd run as Administrator. No restart of Explorer.exe or Windows required.

Comment: With `Run as Administrator`, this worked perfectly for me on **Windows 10** !! :-) Now (install) .exe files that call .bat files work as expected. This solution is much better than having to mess with the registry! As a sidenote, to see what the current association is, simply type `assoc .bat` In my case both `.bat` and `cmd` *were* associated as `Notepad++_file`. Now that they are `.batfile`, right-clicking on bat files allows me to RUN or Run as Administrator.  Before this was not possible. Previously, my workaround was to open a cmd window then manually type a `filename.bat` to run the file

Comment: _Possibly_ the code should be `assoc .cmd=cmdfile` as my quite recent Windows 2016 returns that if I run `assoc .cmd`. (if you want a full list, just run `assoc`)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem (in Windows 7); batch files were opening in Notepad instead of being executed.

Correcting the below registry for .bat files (as per any other machine where it works) will make the batch execute correctly:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\

.bat                --> default-> Value not set
.bat/OpenWithList   --> default-> Value not set
.bat/OpenWithProgIds--> default-> Value not set
                        batfile-> Zero length binary values
```

Keep these entries but remove all others under `.bat`. Refresh and run a batch file by double clicking - it will run correctly.

Comment: A faster way is to open a command prompt as admin and enter
`assoc .bat=batfile`.  This will fix it immediately without the need to restart.

Answer (score 3):

The information in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/49617/135473) led me to the solution to [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/536783/remove-file-association-from-batch-file-type-on-windows-7).

I opened the registry key mentioned there and

- deleted the `UserChoice` key
- removed all entries under the `OpenWithList` key

Answer (score 2):

The answer that got 40 votes by Kaleb didn't work for me but I ended up finding the answer. To get the bat file to execute again, you have to go to:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.bat]` and set (Default) to `batfile`. If you have batch scripts opening in Word or Notepad++ instead of running on double click, it's because those programs have set (Default) to their own mimes.

If you want a quick fix, just open a text file and paste:

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.bat]
    @="batfile"
```

And save it with a .reg extension and double click to merge.

Comment: If this worked for you, great, but the first place Windows checks is Current User (HKCU) not Local Machine (HKLM). If not found in HKCU it will then check HKLM. Check this answer https://superuser.com/a/1056014/47628 for more locations.

Answer (score 1):

In the regisrty you **.bat** entry needs to point to the **batfile** entry:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat]
@="batfile"
.....
```

Naturally you will also need to make sure you have a **batfile** registry entry:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile]
@="MS-DOS Batch File"
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8 use Notepad to make or modify a Batch file but the secret is the following:

Save the batch file using double quotes.
Literally use "MYBACK.BAT" using the double quotes in the save box to save the file.
Instead of MYBACK.BAT

Comment: True (same for previous versions of Windows/Notepad). But how does that answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Again, none of the previous answers did it here.
I for example had to change the default value of `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\batfile\shell]`  from `edit` to `open`.

(Once I had changed the file type extend associations in Explorer folder options dialog. BAT files were & are not offered for change. There seems to be a special exception. But I remember, once I *added* the BAT type in the Explorer folder options dialog, to get 'edit' being the default shell verb.)

### Various places to inspect

So after all there are varying reasons and varying OS version, and (at least) the (default) values of the following registry folders (and subfolders) need to be checked - using some common sense :-). And I think that list may reflect the order of precedence which is relevant to the OS:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat]  (if present: remove "UserChoice")
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.bat]  (if present: @ = "batfile")
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\batfile]  (if present)
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\batfile\shell]  (if present: @ = "open")
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\batfile\shell\open\command]  (if present: @ = "\"%1\" %*")
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.bat]  @ = "batfile"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\batfile]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\batfile\shell]  @ = "open"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\batfile\shell\open\command]  @ = "\"%1\" %*"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat]  @ = "batfile"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell]  @ = "open"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command]  @ = "\"%1\" %*"
```

Comment: Gave you a +1 for listing all the locations and precedence. No one else bothered. (And yes, this is correct order/precedence for file extensions/types.)
RE: Classes Root (HKCR): If you update both the HKLM and HKCU and reboot, the HKCR shouldn't need an edit. It should only be a compilation of the two. "On Windows 2000 and above, HKCR is a compilation of user-based HKCU\Software\Classes and machine-based HKLM\Software\Classes." -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT_(HKCR)

Answer (score 0):

The registry contents vary for different Windows versions.

I suggest that you find another computer with the same O/S version, and use regedit to export the contents of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile`.

Then go to the Boss's machine, delete the above two keys and import the two files.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the hassle (and for many people scariness and intimidation) of editing the registry, you could use the free, excellent, and non-invasive repair utility which actually accomplishes any good (versus *many* other crapware), [tweaking.com Windows Repair](http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html).

Specifically: install it, skip ahead to the "Repairs" tab, click "Open Repairs," and put a checkmark in "04 Register System Files," then click the "Start Repairs" button.

The user interface of that program has changed over time, so in the future, anyone doing this may need to explore the program to find this option.

I would hazard a guess that a lot of other problems exist on your Boss' computer, so that he may want to run all the program's repairs, which can take hours, depending.

Note: I am not affiliated with tweaking.com; I'm just a big fan of the program. Skilled use of it has saved my computer's operating system or solved stubborn problems multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then registry editing use the safer and more direct command line. From an Adminstrator CMD prompt:

By showing *existing* association for the file extension we see that on this machine Windows thinks the file belongs to Notepad++:

```
C:\> assoc .bat
.bat=Notepad++_file
```

Let's find out what command is run for that association:

```
C:\> ftype Notepad++_file
Notepad++_file="C:\ProgramData\scoop\apps\notepadplusplus\current\notepad++.exe" "%1"
```

Search for a different command to run that might be better (`-i` means ignore-case):

```
C:\> ftype | findstr -i bat
batfile="%1" %*
```

Change the association to use this other command:

```
C:\> assoc .bat=batfile
.bat=batfile
```

Done.

#### Notes

This is an improvement of the base answer by @Niklas-R https://superuser.com/a/1273182/16966.

`assoc` and `ftype` on their own list everything.
Don't forget the dot! `assoc bat` and `assoc .bat` are not the same.
Technically cmd should be `assoc .cmd=cmdfile` and not *batfile*, but it doesn't seem to harm or change anything to have them both the same.

Also see:

- https://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html
- https://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html