# how to add menu item in folder right click that calls python script

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, windows-registry

how to add a menu item to any folder right click in windows explorer  that passes the selected folder as argument to the python script ?

I have written a tool in python that takes the folder path as argument and do the slideshow of the images in that folder, for which I want to do this.

Comment: answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/444726/windows-how-to-add-batch-script-action-to-right-click-menu

Answer (score 0):

Open regedit and create a new key in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell` with name `Slideshow` and modify value of `Default` (by right clicking on it in right pane) to `Start slideshow`.

Then you need to create another key in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Slideshow` with name `command`. Modify `Default` value similarly to `myscript.py %1`.