# Python script won't run from the context menu

Tags: windows, command-line, context-menu

Working on the basis of [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/444726/windows-how-to-add-batch-script-action-to-right-click-menu) (and [this follow-up post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946581/adding-batch-script-to-windows-8-context-menu)), I've tried adding a python script (which I've added to the path and so on, so that I can run it from the command line everywhere in the system) to the context menu, but I get a strange error message:

[image]

To be clear, I have successfully run this script from the command line (using powershell, in case it matters) in the folder in which I'm trying to run it from the context menu.

For reference, this is the command in the registry:

```
C:\cmdtools\get_abs.py \"%V\"
```

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the error.

Comment: I did. It's linked. I don't have enough experience points or whatever to embed the picture.

Comment: Can you point out the command you have given in the registry that triggers the launch of the Python script?

Comment: I'll edit it in above.

Answer (score 0):

I reposted this question to stackoverflow and someone answered it.

tl;dr: the context menu will only run `.exe` files, so I had to point the command part of the registry entry to python.exe, followed by my script as an argument.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127532/python-script-wont-run-from-the-context-menu