# Copy file changes modified timestamp?

Tags: windows

Every folder I copy or move from a drive/partition to a different partition it changes its modified date to current date. This does not happen with files, only folders.

If I copy a folder from a drive to the same drive, it keeps the modified date timestamp.

Using robocopy/xcopy works fine but I'd like to fix this issue so that right-click copy and ctrl+c will work keeping timestamps again.

I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro x64 with all updates installed if it matters.

Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if you could write a simple batch script and then make a right click option with Robocopy or XCopy that'll do it for the folder you click on perhaps. Maybe have it prompt for destination and lock down to work for folders only? See [here for example of solutions](https://superuser.com/questions/444726/windows-how-to-add-batch-script-action-to-right-click-menu) you could use for potential workaround to the limitation is there's not registry edit, etc. available for Windows 8.1. Maybe even run a PowerShell script instead, that'd be cool!!

Comment: Title says "copy file", body says "doesn't happen with files", and folders might not even have a modified date. Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025187/rules-for-date-modified-of-folders-in-windows-explorer … - and also, take a look whether your drives are NTFS or FAT