# Windows - Add prefix to selected files names

Tags: windows, batch, rename, prefix

Is there a way natively in Windows to rename multiple selected files in a folder to have a common prefix? Effectively what I want is a way to manually select multiple files, right-click and rename them, but with the option to add a prefix only. I also don't want to install extra software to accomplish this.

I already know about the batch rename by selecting files and pressing F2, but this replaces the entire name and appends a sequential number. I want to keep the current name and only add a prefix.

I also know you can run cmd in the folder and rename files that have common name characters or file attributes, but in my example the files I want to select will not have any shared names and all files in the folder are the same type.

My only solution I can think of is to temporarily move the files to a new folder and batch rename them, then move them back to the original folder. I feel like there has to be a better way than this.

Comment: `gci C:\foo\bar -Filter *.xy | % { rename-item $_.FullName -NewName ("Prefix_" + $_.Name) }`

Comment: @SimonS you don't need to use `%` because `Rename-Item` receives a list of file objects, and you don't need $_.FullName either: `gci C:\foo\bar -Filter *.xy | ren -NewName ("Prefix_" + $_.Name) }`

Answer (score 2):

You may add a batch file (`.bat`) to the right-click Send menu
([link](https://superuser.com/questions/444726/windows-how-to-add-batch-script-action-to-right-click-menu)),
or as a Send-menu destination (in `%USERPROFILE%\SendTo`).

The batch file can handle its parameters using a loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%x in (%*) do ( 
    ...
)
```

and it can also get the prefix using the
[SET/P command](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html),
then issue the appropriate
[REN command](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)
per each file.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in way, without a batch/powershell script, to rename those files. Especially if they don't have a common pattern you will run into issues. There are various tools you can use to do this but you said you're not willing to install additional software.