# Batch file to select an option on a file's right-click menu

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Running Windows

Some files have different right-click menu options. For example, if I right-click a folder, I might have Open, Open in New Window, etc. but if I select a .txt file I'll get Open, Print, Edit, etc.

Some special files created by their respective programs add right-click menu options for those filetypes that don't appear by any default Windows program. For example, I'm using a scripter that makes files I can compile from the right-click menu.

Is there a command line I can throw in a .bat that will open a file using those special right-click options?

Comment: No. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37476927/powershell-cannot-find-some-verbs-of-executable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows: How to add batch-script action to Right Click menu](https://superuser.com/questions/444726/windows-how-to-add-batch-script-action-to-right-click-menu)