# How to use a batch file on the context menu and 'pass on' the rightclicked file?

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg, batch, context-menu

The case: There's a program called gMKVExtractGUI which demuxes MKV videofiles. You can rightclick any MKV, and the program opens that video. It can then extract the subtitles. It doesn't work on MP4 files.

I made a batchfile with an FFmpeg command line that DOES extract subtitles from MP4 video files. The batchfile contains the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i Film(20xx).mp4 -map 0:3 Film(20xx).srt
```

But in order to do that, the name of the right-clicked movie needs to be
'passed on' to the batch file.

This question might SEEM like the one below, but it is not.
[Windows: How to add batch-script action to Right Click menu](https://superuser.com/questions/444726/windows-how-to-add-batch-script-action-to-right-click-menu)

Using ***Default Programs Editor*** from that question solves the problem of adding a command to the context menu. However, it does **not** solve the problem of making that batch file work on the **rightclicked MP4 video-file**, in question.

Questions:

- How do I pass on the movie file name to the batch file?
- What can I use from the quoted question to help me
- If this approach is flawed, what would be a good way of extracting subtitles from MP4's by using the context-menu?

Thanks....

Please remember that I am relatively new, so be kind. Even though some members here have down-voting as a hobby, (especially questions they don't immediately understand), if you do that, you can at least MOTIVATE why you down-vote.

EDIT

Dear Wasif: When I just wanted to test your command in the batchscript with the variable `**"%~1"**`, it produced an error message:  `**%~1: No such file or directory**`
When I ran the the command line with the fixed names (rather than the variables) of video and subtitle, it DID extract the subtitle.

So, I'm not filling that variable `**"%~1"**`. Ideas on how to fill it? Where do I define (declare?) the variable? In the batchfile?

Here's the command line output in DOS:

```
    e:\subbedMP4> b:\Programs\ffmpeg.exe -i "%~1" -map 0:3 "%~dpn1Film(20xx).srt"
    ffmpeg version git-2020-08-31-4a11a6f Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 10.2.1 (GCC) 20200805
      configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
      libavutil      56. 58.100 / 56. 58.100
      libavcodec     58.101.101 / 58.101.101
      libavformat    58. 51.101 / 58. 51.101
      libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
      libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
      libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
      libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
      libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
    %~1: No such file or directory
    
    e:\subbedMP4>
```

Comment: How do you know 0:3 is always a subtitle? You can omit `-map 0:3` and it will automatically choose the first text-based subtitle stream to put into the output. Or if there are multiple input subtitles in the input you can select by language: `-map 0:m:language:eng`

Comment: your 2nd sentence makes no sense. your 3rd sentence seems plausible.

Comment: Translation: if you include `-map 0:3`, and stream 0:3 is not a subtitle stream, then your command will fail. If you do not include `-map 0:3` then ffmpeg will by default automatically choose a subtitle regardless of position. In other words, you don't necessarily need to use `-map`. See [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection). tl;dr - just use `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.srt` if your input only has 1 subtitle stream.

Comment: Oddly enough, you're right, the -map switch is not necessary.  I've tested that, and it did produce the subtitle. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first change the batch file like this:

```
ffmpeg -i "%~1" -map 0:3 "%~dpn1Film(20xx).srt"
```

Then the .REG file will be:

```
Windows Registry Editor 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mp4]
"MUIVerb"="Extract subtitles"
"Position"="Bottom"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mp4\command]
@="\"FULL PATH OF THE BATCH SCRIPT\" \"%1\""
```