# Merge folders via right-click menu

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, merge, files-folders

Is there a way to create a button in the right-click menu of Windows Explorer to merge the content of folders? [Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSCe1.png)

Upd: It could be probably done using information from this question, [Windows: How to add batch-script action to Right Click menu](https://superuser.com/questions/444726/windows-how-to-add-batch-script-action-to-right-click-menu) , but I was hoping there was a ready solution.

Comment: Try https://www.lopesoft.com/index.php/en/products/filemenutools

Comment: @Gantendo Thank you, but unfortunately this tool isn't that handy. Even disregarding the fact the program is paid, its closest feature, Join Folders, requires to specify a new folder name instead of using the name of the selected folder. And even in this case problems arise when you specify an already taken name and there is same files in the folders.

Comment: I think we need a bit more info.

Do you want to merge a bunch of files you select into a predefined list of destination folders? This is do-able with FileMenu Tools.

Or do you just wanna select 2 folders and have them get merged.

Imagine I have folder X and folder Y.
What should happen if I merge X into Y and they contain files/folders with the same name? I use BeyondCompare's Folder compare function to compare 2 folders and it also has a context menu item.

Comment: @Gantendo I looking for a way to merge files within folders, regardless of the number of folders, into one folder. If there is no file name conflict, I want to get just one selected (right-clicked) folder with files from all selected folders. If there is, it would be great to have some renaming options with the ability to rename automatically. It could be probably done using information from this question, https://superuser.com/questions/444726/windows-how-to-add-batch-script-action-to-right-click-menu , but I was hoping there was a ready solution.

Comment: I've bookmarked this question cause I am curious too. Personally, when I move the contents of folder X to folder Y I often use a script that checks if they have subdirectories that "clash" because if that is the case then I do not want the files in those subdirectories to be merged.

Comment: Unclear: Do you want the selected folders copies into another folder? Do you mean the folders as folders, or just their contents?

Comment: @harrymc I want to select many folders and get only one of them with contents of each in it. It would be nice to have different options, though.