# How do I dissociate a program from a file type?

Tags: windows, file-management, file-extension, file-types

If I have a file with the extension `.class` and I opened it with Notepad.  How do I destroy that association so that Notepad is not associated with the `.class` file type? I do not want to change the `.class` association to another program - just remove it.

I use Windows 7.

Comment: … and you don’t even tell us your OS?

Comment: @Kissaki 'Notepad' implies Microsoft Windows

Comment: So … which version of windows? :) The steps necessary *may* differ.

Comment: `I do not want to change the filetype association to another program - just remove it.`   So what do you want to happen when you double-click it? Do you want the *Open with…* dialog? What is the extension? How did you create it in the first place? There are several ways and places that an extension can be registered, so getting rid of it will depend on how/where it was made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [a discussion I found](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-to-manage-file-types-in-windows-7/92dffd14-a131-41a7-94d7-9a298390dd7e), a Microsoft MVP recommended the use of [**this program**, "unassoc.exe"](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/91920-unassociate-file-extention-type.html), perfect for your needs.

`unassoc` is a small portable executable, whose only UI elements include a list of all file types with associations on your computer, the ability to select one or more extensions, and the ability to delete the file type associated with that extension.

[image: Unassoc]

---

Also, if you're simply worried about the overhead of having multiple file extensions registered to a program you don't have installed anymore, the registry cleaner bundled with [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) can automate this process for you.  It can scan for unused file extensions, and delete the relevant registry entries.

Comment: Download not needed, see http://superuser.com/q/569449/78897

Comment: Not for Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Vista you click the Start button and select "Default Programs".  There are several options -- you probably want "Associate a file type or protocol with a program".

Answer (score 1):

Use `regedit` to remove the keys associated with the file extension. Then restart `explorer`.

1. Open `regedit`.

   - <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
   - type `regedit`.
   - <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Delete `.ext` *keys* / *values* from the registry.

   - <kbd>Edit</kbd> -> <kbd>Find</kbd>.
   - Enter extension name **with** *preceding dot* (ex- `.txt`).
   - <kbd>Delete</kbd> found *keys* / *values*.
   - Use <kbd>F3</kbd> to goto next search result.
   - Delete all such *keys* / *values* until end of search.
3. Restart `explorer`.

   - Open `Task Manager`.
   - Find `Windows Explorer`.
   - <kbd>Right Click</kbd> -> <kbd>End Task</kbd>.
   - Repeat the same for remaining `Windows Explorer`.
   - <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> type `explorer` -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This should unassociate the file type.

Comment: In Step 2, which .ext are you talking about? Where is it located?

Answer (score 0):

**Windows XP**

1. Click on the Start menu with your mouse or press the "Windows" button on your keyboard.
2. Click on the "My Computer" option in the Start menu.
3. Click on the "Tools" tab along the menu bar.
4. Click on the "Folder Options" option.
5. Click on the "View" tab.
6. Make sure the "Hide extensions for known file types" is unchecked, so you can see the full filenames in Windows XP, including file type associations.
7. Click "OK" and close the "Folder Options" window.
8. Right-click on a file you wish to change.
9. Click on the "Properties" option in the right-click context menu.
10. Click the "Open with..." button in the "Properties" window. Note that the file may already have a file type association saved for it (it will display the icon of the associated application). Be aware that the button may be captioned "Change..." instead of "Open with...," depending on the version of Windows XP you are using.
11. Click on an application to choose a different file type association for your selected file type. You may also click "Browse" if the application you wish to use for your new file type association is not listed.
12. Click "OK" once you have chosen a file type association.

Via [ehow.com](http://www.ehow.com/how_2052279_change-file-type-associations-windows.html)

**Windows 7**

There is no utility to actually remove, other than registry. So, you could use [this utility](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/unassociate-file-types-windows-7-vista/).

Answer (score -1):

If you have CYGWIN intalled on your windows, it works perfectly.
Just safely change the extension of the file without touching the registery by using "mv" command.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.