# Restore Windows file extension to default

Tags: windows, windows-7

I had a file that Windows did not recognize. It was called `abc.per`. This is the correct extension for the file. The file does not open in any known Windows programs either (this is also not a problem). For some reason, I changed the file to always open with [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29).

Now I want to get rid of the fact that it always needs to open with Notepad, but Windows just doesn't allow me to get rid of this behaviour. I tried to rename the file in which case it loses its extension, that is, `per`.

How do I remove the extension and restore the default behaviour of the file?

I am on a 64-bit Windows 7 system.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue. It was quite simple. I needed to go into the [Windows Registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) and remove the default associated with the extensions. The Super User post *[How do you remove a default program association for file types in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/49615)* is useful.