# Change back to 'Windows can't open this file' (Change Windows Default Programs and File Type Associations)

Tags: windows-7

I opened an unknown application with [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad++) and now every file with that extension is opened by Notepad++ (it was set to always use the selected program to open this kind of file). How do I remove the *Open with Notepad++* and set it to "Windows can't open this file", so I can use Web services?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove its association with Notepad++ from Default Program Settings in the Control Panel, but you must select a New Program. You cannot leave any file type blank or disassociated.
See [Change Windows Default Programs and File Type Associations](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/change-which-programs-windows-uses-by-default)

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem. The other Super User question, *[How do you remove a default program association for file types in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/49615)* may be the way to go.