# Restore .psd thumbnails in Windows 10 by removing default file association in registry

Tags: windows-registry, adobe-photoshop, windows-10, file-types

After upgrading from Windows 8.1 to 10, I noticed that `.psd` Photoshop files started having thumbnails again, something I've not seen since CS2. 
Once I tried to open a `.psd`, it asked me which app I'd like to use by default, so I chose Photoshop CC 2015. However, the thumbnails then disappeared to be replaced with Photoshop icons.

I'm thinking of trying to remove the default file association for `.psd` images, by deleting the registry keys as shown in this answer: https://superuser.com/a/49617/291776

This involves deleting `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.psd` and/or `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.psd`. **If I do this, will I be able to set Photoshop as the default program again (with the Photoshop icon showing on `.psd` files) in case the thumbnails don't come back?**

**UPDATE:**

The method I tried didn't work anyway. `.psd` files still had the Photoshop icon on them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should. The Windows Registry allows you to **export keys**, which means you can right click what you are about to delete, and click `export`, then save a .reg file. This will save your registry settings (the .psd key and all subkeys). Then, if you do not like your changes, you can simply right click the file you created and hit `merge`, and you will have your settings back (you will get a UAC prompt). You might need to log off/ restart to make the changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Please also note, that you might need to open the file in PS CC 2015 once before he detects the thumbnails correctly

You also need to tell Photoshop in the settings that the files should always be saved together with an preview image
(set this to off if you like small psd documents)

And as [ironmanmark20](https://superuser.com/users/437623/ironmanmark20) pinted out correctly: You can export keys by right clicking and exporting as .reg file
When you want to restore the settings just run the .reg file as administrator and all keys and subkeys will be updated to the state they have inside the reg file

Comment: In preferences, it says 'Always save' image previews. And I think that image previews are being saved, but for some reason, the photoshop icon is shown instead of thumbnails when `.psd` files are set to automatically open with photoshop. But in any case, deleting the reg keys didn't do anything

Comment: Previews will only show if you reach a specific i con size. Are the icons still hidden once you turn ob the icon size on your explorer window?

Comment: Changing the icon size in file explorer doesn't show thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

I heard that there is the issue with Adobe thumbnails in Windows 8 to 10. You can use [SageThumbs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sagethumbs) until adobe patches this issue.

You may also need to adjust PSD file size in the setting of SageThumbs to make bigger file size PSDs also viewable.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a fix that works for me.  I found a site that would allow you to download the older version of Adobe XL reader.

- Before installation I de-installed Adobe DC.
- Then installed the XL version.
- Went to Windows explorer to locate a .pdf
- Right clicked the file to select open with Adobe XL, then closed it.
- Closed explorer then reopened.
- All .pdf files now display thumbnails.
- Set XL not to update else you will have the same problem again.

I will keep the old copy of Adobe XL until this problem is resolved.

Comment: This question is about .psd files, not .pdf

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I can generate thumbnails for PSDs that show up in Explorer (I'm using Windows 10 64-bit) by using the free image utility [Irfanview.](http://www.irfanview.com/)

I just open Irfanview, go to File > Open, and navigate to a folder containing PSDs. You will see thumbnails appear for each PSD as Irfanview generates them. Once this is finished (which usually only takes a few seconds, depending on the number of PSDs), refresh the folder in Windows Explorer to get the thumbnails to show there as well.